# Can Vue + Laravel be used to make non-single page applications?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I want to make a website that uses Vue.js and Laravel ... it seems like every tutorial is for making SPAs. For my specific application, an SPA does not make sense. I do not understand how to structure my Vue code, since it requires a different instance to be made on each page, with different methods, etc. If I try to instantiate a separate a vue instance on a per-page basis, I have to include a CSRF token in my request header each time which doesn't feel right.

What is the general architecture for a multiple page laravel application with vue?

Comment: It can **only be used to make non SPAs**, an SPA requires Vue Router which is a different thing

Comment: I tried adding a new Vue instance to each page, like you said in my previous question, but that requires me to include the CSRF token on every page, whereas I'd rather just have it set in the axios settings once in bootstrap->app.php

Comment: CSRF token is for axios, has nothing to do with Vue instance

Answer (score 3):

> every tutorial is for making SPA

The default Laravel 5.8 install comes with VueJS preinstalled and configured **WITHOUT AN SPA**

Just don't use the Vue Router

in Laravel 6+ the Vue preset via `laravel/ui` is configured the same way

> I do not understand how to structure my Vue code

Make different Vue instances in different script files instead of one global instance in `app.js`

> I have to include a CSRF token in my request header each time

No, that has nothing to do with Vue, move this code

```js
window.axios = require('axios');
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
```

to `bootstrap.js` and load the script in `app.blade.php` after compiling it in `webpack.mix.js`

that's if you don't want to include `app.js` everywhere, or instead just remove the Vue global instance from that file

Hope this helps

Comment: I have done this, but I still get 405 Method Not Allowed errors when I make calls from individual scripts on my pages

Comment: 405 is when you make a get request to a post route or vice versa, has nothing to do with the instances, show that axios call so we can help you with that

Comment: At what position on the page do you include your script reference tag to app.php? At the end of the body or in the header of the main layout blade file?

Comment: if you want the scripts to load before the content => the header with `defer` attribute, otherwise at the end of body (but before other scripts that uses Vue)